# Display: inline not working properly

Tags: css

```
header ul {
  display: inline; }
  header ul .nav-header li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 1em;
    float: left; }
  header ul a {
    text-decoration: none; }

*{ border: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

this is my css now using the reset wildcard seems to cancel out the display: inline; anyone know a fix?

The issue here is if you delete the wild card the Welcome header is displayed on the line after the navbar. Where as currently its on the same line, using display: inline; should remove that but didn't.

http://jsfiddle.net/P8QmL/

Comment: An `<ul>` should only contain `<li>` as direct child elements... Also, you never really told us what your problem is, or at least what you expect your code to do.

Comment: Even so it still doesn't work removing them. updated for clarity

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply your `display:inline` to the `header` not the `header ul`.

You should also remove the divs within your ul.

html:

```
<header>
      <ul class='nav-header'>
          <li>
            Kali @ 1000 Commercial
          </li>

            <li>
              <a href="/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/products">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="/about">About</a>
            </li>
      </ul>
    </header>
    <section class='body-wrapper'>
      <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <div class='nav-footer'>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="/contact">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </footer>
```

css:

```
header {
  display: inline; }

  header .nav-header li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 1em;
    float: left; }

  header ul a {
    text-decoration: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I understand now.

Here's the problem:

An element (e.g. `<header>`) containing all floating elements "loses" its size. Thus, your `<header>` element has a width and height of 0, even though it contains non-zero elements. As a consequence, the subsequent elements ignore the header element (since its size is 0) and appear to "float" to the right.

There are a few fixes, but the best one is probably to use the css `clear` property on your subsequent elements:

```
section {
    clear: both;
}
```

I have taken the liberty to improve your HTML & CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/P8QmL/4/

I should note this still doesn't give your `<header>` element any size, so should you wish to style your header, you'll notice nothing happens since the header is still of size 0.
So if you need your header to have e.g. a background color, you have to use a different solution. The easiest one to give an element with floating children a size is to use `overflow: auto`. It's kind of hacky, but it works.

```
header {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```